# Failure sending mail

Tags: asp.net

I have a problem in this code i am new please help me

Error is : Could not send the e-mail - error: Failure sending mail.

Here is my code:

```
try
{
    MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
    mailMessage.To.Add(emaild_id);
    mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(my_email_id);
    mailMessage.Subject = "Info";
    mailMessage.Body = "something.....";
    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("my site name like web.com");                            
    smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Label1.Text="Could not send the e-mail - error: " + ex.Message;
}
```

Comment: Did you put `smtp` settings for the sending server in your web.config?

Comment: Is "my site name" a name of actual SMTP server?

Comment: What I have to write in web.config can you help me. @Floremin

Comment: Use https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer

Comment: You need to have a correctly configured smtp service on your web server, or somewhere accessible to your web server. **This is not trivial to get right.** There are a lot of gotcha's in setting up smtp, such that you do end up sending the messages, but they never reach their recipients. Instead, the messages will get blocked by ISP and e-mail service spam filters, simply because one or more of the anti-spam features you need to configure (like rDNS, DKIM, or SFP) is not exactly perfect.

Comment: I strongly suggest that you never use `ex.Message` if you're trying to find out what the problem is. Use `ex.ToString()`.

Answer (score 0):

Enter your `smtp` server settings in web.config, under `<mailSettings> ... <network>`. Take a look at the spec for `<mailSettings>` in web config:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164240(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score -1):

You need to configure your smtp server. For eg if you have gmail account you can use gmail smtp server for testing as

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential( your gmail address, your gmail password);
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Timeout = 3000;
client.Send(mail);
```

or you can configure your web.config as

```
<system.net>
 <mailSettings>
  <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
    <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="your email" password="your password" defaultCredentials="false" enableSsl="true" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```